# Get Highchart Styled Mode via npm

Tags: javascript, highcharts, npm

This may seem like a very basic question but i cant seem to find the answer anywhere.

Highcharts version 5 comes with a "styled-mode", that allows you to style your chart via css. I installed highcharts via npm. [The Documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css) gives information on how to download the files for styled mode from their website, but not how to get it via npm, or switch to it shomehow by code.

How can i activate styled-mode for the charts in my application?

Comment: As of 7.0.0, styled mode can be toggled by setting the option **chart.styledMode** to `true`. The `highcharts/js/` folder has been removed.  
Sources:
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/#highcharts-v7.0.0
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-dist/commit/98322c60c47d1bc5faa92a4de32cd479f5bb8fc8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styled mode Highcharts is available in `highcharts/js/` folder. Default stylesheet can be found in `highcharts/css`. You do not need to activate them - just include them in your html file.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using ES6 modules, you simply import the styled-mode JavaScript module instead of the standard module.

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/js/highcharts';
```

You will likely also want to include their default stylesheet. They provide an SCSS file as well, so in your application's SCSS file, you will want to import their stylesheet:

```
@import "~highcharts/css/highcharts";
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when using Highcharts-Vue and webpack. My solution was to copy the styled-mode `highcharts.js` file over top of the one installed by npm in the `node_modules/highcharts/` folder.